# Error in calling a method from a WCF web service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, c#-4.0

In my asp.net project there are class libraries called DataLayer, BusinessLayer, ModelLayer and the Web application project. i have added a WCF webservices project to the solution. In the WCF i have implemented a simple method

```
public string GetName(string name)
        {
            var Garage = new GarageView_ML();
            {
                Garage.GarageName = name;
            };
            return new GarageView_DL().GetNameDL(Garage);
        }
```

In the DataLayer class GarageView_DL i have implemented the following method

```
 public string GetNameDL(GarageView_ML ml)
        {
            return "OK" + ml.GarageName;
        }
```

The "return" in the line `return new GarageView_DL().GetNameDL(Garage);` is underlined with dark blue color giving the error

> The type 'System.Web.UI.Page' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. E:\TestProjects\Myapp\WebApplication1\MVCS_WCFService\Service1.cs   42  13  MVCS_WCFService

I have tried adding the System.web reference but it didn't work. Any help is apprciated to solve the issue. thanks in advance.

ps: i can access other layers(Model and business) without any issue. Error comes only when accessing the datalayer.

Comment: I assume WCF project has reference to your DataLayer assembly? :)

Comment: @grapkulec Yes i have added the assembly. It detects the class object GarageView_DL() and the method GetNameDL

Comment: is this mvc or webforms? do u reference the page class anywhere in ur model or view

Comment: @Legends It is a webforms project. In views only i have referenced page class.

Comment: U do something wrong there should be no reference to the page class needed when accessing a webservice ! Why do u want to reference the page class in the webservice?

Comment: @Legends What is meant was in interface files(aspx files) in the web application i have extended with page class. But in WCF project library i have not used page class.

Comment: so u have added a reference to system.web with that token: b03f5f7f11d50a3a ??? Did u check the token and version of the ref assembly?

Comment: @Legends I did not understand what you tried to say. i just looked at web config. there is no assembly with details System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a. Can you state how to check it.

Comment: In ur project under References, click on the system.web reference if there is any and press F4.